# ICMP socket (win)

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2, icmp

I wanted to make a program as a checknet if the adress is up return 1 if it is down return 0. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

static void init(void)
{

    WSADATA wsa;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        puts("WSAStartup failed !");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

static void end(void)
{

    WSACleanup();

}

int chknet(char * ip) 
{ 
    struct sockaddr_in name; 
    struct hostent * hent; 
    int sock; 
    int retour = 0; 
init();
/* creat socket  icmp */ 
           if(!(sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP))) return (-1); 
                     memset(&name,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 
                     name.sin_family = AF_INET; 
                     name.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip); 
           if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &name,sizeof(struct sockaddr))==0) retour = 1; 
           else retour = 0; 

end();
return(retour); 
}
// Fonction main *************************** 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *adress="www.stackoverflow.com";
    int a= chknet(adress);
   printf("result %d\n",a);
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

When I am connected to the internet it returns 1 but even when I am not connected it returns  1 too, but it should return 0. 
THX

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the string `"www.stackoverflow.com"` to function `inet_addr()`. This functions expects a "IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation" address, something like `151.101.1.69` -- so you need to do a DNS lookup first, by using something like `gethostbyname()`.

It's always a good idea to check the return codes from functions you call...

Comment: but I am getting a 1 in the both cases. For exemple if I make in the adress="12.2" it will return 1. However there is no such adress in my network.

Comment: It's possible `connect()` is returning ok, because of some random value in `s_addr`. How about using an actual address of something on your local network? And checking the actual value of returned error codes, perhaps printing them with `perror()`. Else you're just guessing.

Comment: I worry about this (from my manual page): `The  inet_addr()  function converts  the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte  order.   If  the input  is  invalid, INADDR_NONE (usually -1) is returned.  Use of this function is problematic because -1 is a valid address (255.255.255.255). Avoid its use in favor of inet_aton(), inet_pton(3), or getaddrinfo(3), which provide a cleaner way to indicate error return.` You should check you're getting what you expect, or take the advice to not use that function.

Comment: My point is, something is going wrong, but we don't know what. To track that down, check the return codes of *every* function you call, until you find the problem.